# Why xamarin app crashed after publish?

Tags: android, xamarin

I create my android app via xamarin and deploy it.In this case app worked currently but when publish app and install it on emulator app crashed.
I open new project with out any code.I put a button inside main activity and then setting up such as this image and repeat publish but app installed and when running  crashed.

What is problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The "Android Options" are much more interesting when you can't startup your application. What is your "Linking" option and is the "ProGuard" enabled? BTW, your API levels are quite low, at least the "Target Android version" should be about 7, this doesn't mean that the application cannot run on older versions.

Comment: Your question is missing the crash logs

Comment: @cricket_007  How to get crash log?

Comment: I haven't done it in Xamarin, but you can always run the `adb logcat` command to get them from your device... My point is that it's impossible to fix your app crashing without reading those

Answer (score 0):

I m new to Xamarin and recently i Have developed and app and Published  successfully i Also had Face savarel errors on Releasing

**Resons Behind Crashing The App :**
There Can be Savarel Reasons of Crashing a Xamarin App After Releasing

- The Default Behaviour of any Xamarin app is to throw exception on any critical error.. so We Have to Digg into Other problems rather Then Focussing on crashing App
  **Lets Discuss Some that I Faced ..**

**1.Project Release (Miss) Configuration**

- The Project Config Worked For me Was :

  - Set Project from Debug to Release Mode (Right Click on Solution).
  - Uncheck option "Use Fast Deploymnet"
  - keep "use" incremental Android Packaging System(aapt2)
  - Dex Compiler : whatever you like
  - code Shrinker: Whatever dex Compiler Support or you can keep it
    Blank
  - Keep "Enable developer instrumentation(debugging and Profilling)"
    unCheked (must)
  - Linking : dont keep None keep it "sdk only" or "sdk and User
    Assambly"
  - keep Target Android Version(ANdroid Menifest) lower or Equal to
    option Compile using Android version(Aplication)

**2.Un-Supported Libraries in projectname.Android & Projectname.ios**

-1 of the app crashing reasons is this also .. let me explain

- every xamarin project installs a xamarin library by default
- and it can be older version then libraries available in letest
  version
- Eg: i was having a plugin for Toast Notification with version 2.2.0

  - initiasly in my device project was working fine in Android 10 in
    both release and debug mode but but but....,
    it was crashing in other versions devices like 11,12,13,9,8..
    because of the xamarin library version was older and not supported
    new library versions in these devices
  - Solution : what i did was re-installed that plugin with version
    2.0.0(DownGraded version) And It Worked ..!! in release and Debug
    Mode..
- Eg2:**Installing UnNessesary Libraries to projectName.Android And
  projectName.ios Projects**

  - i had installed a library that was for only experimental perpose
    and later i didn't Used any code from that library in my project
    and i was facing error like : "Java.lang.ClassnotFound Exception"
    in release mode and app was crashing without any reason
  - Solution i Removed that library from all 3 projects
    .ios,.android,and .csproject it worked errors ware gone!
- **Installing Un-Nessessary Libraries to .Android and .Ios project**
- look buddy you dont need every library to be installed in .Android and
  .ios Project always Sometimes if you are installing those in only
  .csproject(pcl) Project ..! it is sufficiant to run code.

  **Note!:** *Try To Install As minimum number of libreries as possible
  in .Android And .Ios Project*
- **Signing The Apk After Publishing(Archiving)**
- One of the major Reason is not Signing Your Apk in publishing(Archiving
  Process)
- For This Check link: [How to Prepare for Deploy And Sign xamarin APP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows)